# Word for covering yourself with something while slouching?

Tags: single-word-requests

It's what you usually do when the weather is cold. Example:

> We walked through the snow, [...] is within/inside our coats.

Comment: google translate gave `swaddle` or `muffle` for the French word I would have used in this case (emmitoufler).

Comment: *Huddle* answers the title; *hunker*, the example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps *[huddle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/huddle)*

> Curl one’s body into a small space:
>   *the watchman remained, huddled under his canvas shelter*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

and

> To draw or curl one's limbs close to one's body: *huddled under the blanket while watching television.*

*[American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=huddle)*

Comment: 'Huddle' implies that you are grouping together with others. If you're the only person in your coat, then you're not huddled in your coat. There are some secondary meanings, which you posted, but the connotation of the primary meaning remains, and I rarely hear anyone use these other ones.

Comment: @DCShannon only if you watch too much football. I have no qualms with this usage

Comment: @Dodgie In the two posted links, the first definitions for 'huddle' as a verb are "Crowd together; nestle closely" and "1. To crowd together, as from cold or fear." The only other meaning that doesn't involve multiple people is the one posted in this answer, which involves curling up your limbs. Hard to walk that way.

Comment: @DCShannon two definitions to one, i guess i lose ;)

Answer (score 10):

[Since I was beaten to *huddle*...]

> ***hunker***
>
> Bend the top of one’s body forward; hunch

It's often used with *down*:

"We walked through the snow, hunkered down inside our coats."

Comment: +1 I agree. And it has a youthful, slangy tone I like.

Comment: I'd disagree, at least with "hunkered down". This usually implies being stationary.  From thefreedictionary.com, 1. to crouch or squat; to sit on one's haunches. 
 2. to settle in at a location for an extended period; - also (figuratively) to maintain a position and resist yielding to some pressure, as of public opinion. 
 3. to take shelter, literally or figuratively; to assume a defensive position to resist difficulties.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast The third definition you yourself cite fits the walking example just fine and mentions nothing about mobility. Shelter doesn't have to be stationary.

Comment: Shelter does not have to be stationary, but "To take shelter" usually does. One does not take shelter in moving bus, for instance. The example given was too long to include in a comment: "
While many businessmen were hunkering down for another bust after the lean years of the Second World War and the Great Depression before it, Taylor and company correctly reckoned it was the dawn of an era of prosperity and growth.
- Richard Siklos [Shades of Black, 1995]"

Comment: Walking while 'hunkering' seems paradoxical. If I'm hunkered, I'm specifically not going anywhere. The 1st definition for 'hunker down' on Wiktionary matches WhatRoughBeast's 3rd definition, but the 2nd one is "(idiomatic) To stubbornly hold to a position", and the definition for 'hunker' is "(intransitive) To crouch or squat close to the ground".

Answer (score 6):

[**Snuggled**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/snuggle)

> We walked through the snow, **snuggling** under our coats.

The term *snuggle* is more commonly used in the following: "to snuggle under the covers/blankets" but there's nothing to suggest that the protagonists cannot *snuggle* while they *wrap* themselves in their coats. Alternatively...

> We walked through the snow, **wrapped** in our coats.

Comment: Tricky, especially when the subject is plural. To me, "we were snuggling under our coats" evokes imagery of people embracing intimately and comfortably under a shared coat. This might work against the asker's original intent, especially if the focus is on isolation and/or discomfort.

Comment: @talrnu I do agree, but it is possible to share a coat and there's also the added bonus of intimacy and cosiness. But if the air was particularly nippy, there's nothing to exclude them from wearing their own coats and *snuggling* with one another.

Comment: Wrapped sounds pretty reasonable, although it doesn't imply slouching. I completely agree with talrnu that snuggle doesn't work here though.

Comment: wrapped scores over snuggle/cuddle etc

Answer (score 4):

### Hunch

From Wiktionary:

> Verb
>
> **hunch** (third-person singular simple present hunchs, present participle hunching, simple past and past participle hunched)
>
> 1. (intransitive) To slouch, stoop, curl, or lean.
>
>    *Do not hunch over your computer if you want to avoid neck problems.*

I would phrase your example sentence as:

> We walked through the snow, hunched over in our coats.

When your muscles tense up and you feel all tight due to the cold, you are hunched over. If you're perfectly warm, this might not be the right word for you.

Comment: This was my first thought, and what I'd go with.